# unity LookAt Instead Forward

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

The red line is the forward vector of the leg.

[image]

Like in the photo above, I want my legs to look at the red sphere.

I tried using the LookAt function, but it was impossible

What should I do?

Any examples would be appreciated!

Comment: What code did you try?

Comment: you can use `transform.up`, `transform.forward` or `transform.right` for each of the your local axis in world coords. You might be after `LookAt(transform.right)`. If not the case please show what you tried and clarify

Comment: @rustyBucketBay `LookAt(Vector3)` expects a position, not a direction, so unless the leg's position is in a very specific range of positions, that probably wont work as expected